# PHP recognizes array, that comes from file_get_contents() as string, though it is in right format

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I recieve information with file_get_contents() and assign it to var like this:

```
$values = array();
$values = trim(file_get_contents($newurl));
echo gettype($values); // will show "string"
```

When i echo $values, i see that it is a string like:

> [["EUR", "80"],["TRY", "50"],["USD", "40"],["GBP", "60"]];

And gettype($values) also shows "string" instead of array. But if i do

```
$values = [["EUR", "80"],["TRY", "50"],["USD", "40"],["GBP", "60"]];
echo gettype($values); // will show "array"
```

It will show me that $values is an array.

How can i tell php that trim(file_get_contents($newurl)) is an array, not a string?

Comment: Assuming that your file follows JSON rules (which your example does, except for the trailing `;`), just do `$values = json_decode(file_get_contents($newurl), true);` to decode the JSON into a PHP array.

Comment: HTTP only sends data as strings. There is no concept of "arrays" in a HTTP payload. It's up to the server to serialize the data into a string (like using json_encode()) before returning data to the client and to the client to unserialize it (like using json_decode()) when receiving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$values = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents($newurl)), 1);
echo gettype($values); // Array
```

Answer (score 1):

1 [use json](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) ( favoured since you can have assiocative arrays/objects parsed from there

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

2 either [use the web-style parameter encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

3 (danger , might fail) [use the explode functions](https://www.parthpatel.net/php-string-to-array/)

```
$string = 'Hello World';
$arr = str_split($string, 3);
print_r($arr);
//Array ( [0] => Hel [1] => lo [2] => Wor [3] => ld )
```

for 2 and 3 you will have to apply other tricks since this won't easily work recursive

Comment: Example 2 doesn't make much sense. If you, for some reason, needed that, it would be a very custom edge case.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a function which test if it's a json string :

```
function isJsonString($ent){
if(!is_string($ent))
return false;
json_decode($ent);
return json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE;
}
```

and then, test :

```
if(isJsonString($values))
$values = json_decode($values); // --> stdObject
```